# Android - Differentiating between application starting and a restart due to memory being reclaimed by operating system

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

If I am running my app, and I put it into the background, and then disable a permission, it "restarts" the app. However it is not consistent in what it does. The app only has a single activity.

These are the scenarios than occur on restart

> 1. The activity OnCreate bundle is not null, and OnRestoreInstanceState is called
> 2. The activity OnCreate bundle is null, and OnRestoreInstance state is not called.

I'm not sure why scenario 2 occurs, the only apps running are my app, and the settings app, so I don't think it is a resource issue. I would have thought that saveInstanceState would have been called, and so the bundle should not be null on restart.

It seems to be random as to whether 1 or 2 happens.

I am trying to tell the difference between a user manually starting the app, and scenario 2.

Up till now, I have been relying on the Activity OnCreate bundle being null to determine that a user has manually started the app. But because of scenario 2 I cannot do that anymore.

Is there any way to determine between a manual start and scenario 2

Comment: Why do you need to know the difference? I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between your Activity being destroyed and an application being killed.  Being killed for resources is the first.  CHanging permissions is the second.  In that case, your app is forcibly restarted because you may not be able to do things you used to do, and this is the cleanest method to make sure everything is cleared correctly.  As a result, there is no previous bundle to restart with, you're in a fresh launch state.

Comment: Hi Gabe, why do you think I see two different behaviours when I change the permission. From your explanation, I should only see scenario 2. But when I change a permission, I randomly get either scenario 1 or scenario 2.

Comment: Possibly based on enabling/disabling?  Disabling has to kill the app.  Its possible enabling is nicer.

Comment: All my tests are only disabling the permission.